# How to convert from String to IQ object in Smack

Tags: java, android, ejabberd, smack

I'm making IQ requests for saving some data. In order to be synced with ejabberd server, I save IQ data to SQLite database in case of failure. So I convert IQ object to String by `iqObject.toXML().toString()`. But I'm stuck When I read from database and convert into IQ class.

My question is: How to convert following String to IQ class?

```
<iq type='set' id='1001'>
<query xmlns='urn:xmpp:contacts' clean="false" domain='localhost'>
<add>
<i id="1" number="+90">Mesut</i>
<i id="2" number="+91">Umit</i>
<i id="3" number="unknown">Unknown</i>
</add>
<delete>
<i id="4" />
<i id="5" />
</delete>
</query>
</iq>
```

Any helps would be very appreciated.
Best regards...

### Update1

- My smack version is: 4.5.0-alpha1

> The problem is not related with neighter ejabberd nor openfire. It is exactly related with *Smack*

Atention please, the problem is not sending or receiving IQ packets. I make these works successfully. My question is how to send the String above over Smack as IQ stanza packet, so that receive appropriate IQ response.

Answer (score 0):

You approach is true to convert that IQ object into XML, then String.

First you need to go through with the official document of ejabberd server website: https://www.ejabberd.im/IQ%20handlers/index.html

Now, you have to understand how IQ object raw packet are receiving in this thread:  https://discourse.igniterealtime.org/t/how-can-i-create-send-and-receive-raw-iq-packet/71540

Comment: I know how stanza packets are received by ejabberd and I wrote a module in ejabberd for it. The issue is here, completely related with smack. And these links doesn't explain my question.